# Apache 2.4 on Debian issue - "Forbidden" after upgrading virtual host

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4, debian-jessie

I have tried many suggestions I can find via Google to make my virtual host work properly after upgrading from Debian to Jessie (upgrade from Apach 2.2 to 2.4).

I have mod_rewrite and mod_access_compat, which is why it seems to work fine when I use the old syntax. As soon as I go to `Require all granted`, it stops working and I get 403 Forbidden.

I have many virtual hosts and it's the same accross the board... most are Drupal installs. Here's an example of a virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.skyjacobs.com
    Redirect 301 / http://skyjacobs.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin skyjacobs@gmail.com
    ServerName skyjacobs.com
DocumentRoot /www/sky
<Directory /www/sky>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny  # These 2 lines work 
        allow from all    # 
        Require all granted   # If I use this line only, it stops working
</Directory>
    ErrorLog /www/logs/sky/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /www/logs/sky/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

If I comment out the 2 lines of old syntax and use `Require all granted`, it stops working. Does anyone know what the problem might be? Thanks for any leads.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong module for your configuration.
Based on documentation there are 2 modules.

- [mod_access_compat](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html) which is the compatibility module for old syntax
- [mod_access_host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html) which is the new module with new syntax

If you want to change to new syntax, you shall enable `mod_access_host` and disable `mod_access_compat`. Otherwise you could stay on the old syntax with the `mod_access_compat`.

Comment: I do seem to have the new syntax module installed by default with the upgrade: "Module authz_host already enabled". Do I have to disable mod_access_compat for mod_authz_host to do it's magic?

Comment: Yes, I would say so. But as explanation, the module which you're loading later is overwriting settings of previous loaded modules. I would guess, that you're `mod_access_compat` is loaded later than `mod_access_host`.